# HTML - rowspan="2" does nothing while rowspan="3" works perfectly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm try to make a table that looks like

[image]

The problem I have is that when I am trying to merge 2 rows where it says **Ciastka**, **Netto** and **Brutto** they are changing into 1 single row like this:

[image]

**Snippet is below**:

```css
table,thead,tbody,th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
  width: 50%;
}
thead{
  text-align: center;
}
.tyt{
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #42b0f2;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Pieczywo</th>
    <th colspan="2">Cena</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="tyt">
    <td>Bułki</td>
    <td>Chleb</td>
    <td>Ciastka</td>
    <td>Netto</td>
    <td>Brutto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The weird thing is that when I tried to do this table in Word, literally the same thing happened. Can any one explain why this happen?

Comment: I see 0 deference beside height... I don't understand the problem...

Comment: You have `rowspan="3"` followed by a single row. That's two rows. Add another row to span.